# Directory/Prefix with 40,000 objects locks windows explorer and other applications

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

Here at work we use s3fs because our product uses Oracle and the legacy code load files uploaded thru web direct from Oracle pl/sql, so we need the Oracle Database to see the same file system the web server sees. And we cannot access the OS where Oracle is installed to mount Windows shares thru SAMBA.

The problem is, when a directory (prefix in s3) reaches rougly
40,000 files, the access to this directory thru samba become extremely slow, causing timeouts and even completely stop the application pool trying to access this directory.

Our web servers are EC2 instances with Windows 2019.

I wonder if someone know a solution to this.

Comment: Do you use s3fs-fuse or the S3 functionality of Samba, confusingly also named s3fs?

Comment: Hi @AndrewGaul. It's fuse-s3fs.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417381/s3fs-directory-listings-slow-caching-somehow-possible for more information.

Answer (score 0):

S3 LIST API is slow when objects are lots. It should be better if you could re-organize files into multiple directory levels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).